# How do I pass a byte array to a function which accepts a byte slice?

Tags: go, types, arguments

Lets say I have a

```
Type T [64]byte
```

And I want to fill an object of type T with random bytes using "crypto/rand" package.

```
T obj
rand.Read(obj)
```

Obviously this doesn't work so how can I do it.I thought the type declaration at the top was equivalent of typedef in C++.

Comment: `Read` takes a slice, and it looks like you are trying to define an array (the syntax here is not valid Go). The "Tour of Go" covers this here: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7

Answer (score 1):

As JimB noted, you're trying to pass a `[64]byte` to a function that takes a `[]byte`, and these types are not equivalent. You can pass a slice over the whole array and it works fine:

```
rand.Read(obj[:])
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/eARFfn4bDzQ

This is covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7).